# Initiating system restart from kernel space

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, reboot

I have a custom embedded board running linux with an interrupt in a driver monitoring it's 24V power source. If the source goes down battery power takes over and a IRQ fires off. I want to initiate a reboot after 30 seconds running on the battery which powers the board down gracefully.

Currently

```
emergency_sync();
kernel_restart(NULL);
```

Does work but it just brings the system down suddenly after about half a minute after the call to kernel_restart is made. There is no announcement of restart and the system seems to run normally until it happens. Can i initiate a "init 6" or restart with an announcement which shuts down everything orderly (like running reboot on the commandline) from kernel space in some nice manner ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the function `ctrl_alt_del()` does what you want. It sends a signal to `init` to start the normal reboot sequence.

Comment: This worked after adding a clause in inittab to capture ctrl_alt_del and perform the reboot. Cheers.